# Musixtex Chant pentagram using Beamer

Tags: beamer, musixtex

It is needed to code chant pentagram using Beamer. The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixlyr}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\frametitle{?`Qué es \underline{Musixtex}?}

\begin{music}
\font\A=phvb8t at 10pt
\generalmeter{\meterC}
\parindent10mm
\instrumentnumber{2}
\setstaffs1{2}
\setclef16
\setclef2\treble
\setname1{\A Piano}
\setname2{\A Canto}
\setinterstaff{1}{13}%Dist. Sistemas
\nobarnumbers
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Letras}{Ma-nca so-lle-ci-ta pi\`u de-ll'u-sa-to, a-nco-rch\`e}
\setsongraise2{-1.8mm}
\startpiece\addspace\afterruleskip% 
\A\assignlyrics2{Letras}
\znotes|\zchar{10}{\hspace*{-0.7cm}\A Adagio.}&\zchar{10}{\hspace*{-0.7cm}\A Adagio.}\en
\NOtes\hp|\islurd0c\hu{c}&\hu{c}\en
\NOtes\qp|\qu{d}&\qu{d}\en
\NOtes\isluru1P\ql{_P}|\tslur0{c}\zq{c}\qu{e}&\qu{e}\en\bar
%2do
\NOtes\ql{O}|\islurd2c\hl{c}\bsk\isluru3l\qu{f}&\qu{f}\en
\NOtes\ql{L}|\qu{g}&\qu{g}\en
\NOtes\tslur1{M}\ql{M}|\tslur2{c}\ql{c}\bsk\tslur3{n}\qu{h}&\qu{h}\en
\NOtes\qp|\qp&\qp\en\bar
%3er
\NOtes\hp|\islurd0d\hu{d}&\hu{d}\en
\NOtes\qp|\qu{e}&\qu{e}\en
\NOtes\isluru1Q\ql{Q}|\tslur0{d}\zq{d}\qu{^f}&\qu{^f}\en\bar
%4to
\NOtes\ql{_P}|\islurd2d\hl{d}\bsk\isluru3m\qu{g}&\beginmel\islurd0g\qu{g}\en
\NOtes\ql{^M}|\qu{h}&\tslur0{h}\endmel\qu{h}\en
\NOtes\tslur1{N}\ql{N}|\tslur2{d}\ql{d}\bsk\tslur3{o}\qu{_i}&\qu{_i}\en
\NOtes\qp|\qp&\qp\en\bar
%5to
\NOtes\qp|\zh{_i}\isluru0k\hl{k}&\hl{k}\en
\NOtes\isluru1L\ql{L}|&\en
\NOtes\ql{M}|\zq{h}\qu{j}&\ql{j}\en
\NOtes\tslur1{O}\qu{_I}|\tslur0{o}\zq{g}\qu{i}&\ql{_i}\en
\endpiece
\end{music}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow:
[image: desired]

Comment: How are you compiling? I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/Coi7g.png from your code

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Try with `musixtex -l -p ...`

Comment: I am using Overleaf to compile the project... Is there another way to handle this issue? When I use report instead of Beamer it works ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: as you should know in the meantime: please do not post improvements of your question as an answer.

Second:
MusixTeX does not like empty space after braces. So in my answer I put the quasi obligatory % after the braces.
As far as I can see, `\centering` and then inserting an `\hspace` does not make sense. I disactivated the `\centering`. I added a positive `\hspace`. Compiling, you should have gotten an error message, e.g. 'overfull box', due to your scaling.

With compiling in XeLaTeX (in TeXShop) and musixflx, and compiling again, this code gives the attached result:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage{showframe}%
\usepackage{musixtex}%
\input{musixlyr}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, bending, decorations.markings}%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]%
\frametitle{?`Qué es \underline{Musixtex}?}%

%\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,scale=1] (image) at (0,0) {%
\hspace*{0.5cm}%
\begin{music}%
\font\A=phvb8t at 10pt
\font\B=phvb8t at 7pt
\generalmeter{\meterC}%
\parindent10mm
\instrumentnumber{2}%
\setstaffs1{2}%
\setclef16
\setclef2\treble
\setname1{\A Piano}%
\setname2{\A Canto}%
\setinterstaff{1}{13}%Dist. Sistemas
\nobarnumbers
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Letras}{Ma-nca so-lle-ci-ta pi\`u de-ll'u-sa-to, a-nco-rch\`e}%
\setsongraise2{-1.8mm}%
\startpiece\addspace\afterruleskip% 
\B\assignlyrics2{Letras}%
\znotes|\zchar{10}{\hspace*{-0.7cm}\A Adagio.}&\zchar{10}{\hspace*{-0.7cm}\A Adagio.}\en
\NOtes\hp|\islurd0c\hu{c}&\hu{c}\en
\NOtes\qp|\qu{d}&\qu{d}\en
\NOtes\isluru1P\ql{_P}|\tslur0{c}\zq{c}\qu{e}&\qu{e}\en\bar
%2do
\NOtes\ql{O}|\islurd2c\hl{c}\bsk\isluru3l\qu{f}&\qu{f}\en
\NOtes\ql{L}|\qu{g}&\qu{g}\en
\NOtes\tslur1{M}\ql{M}|\tslur2{c}\ql{c}\bsk\tslur3{n}\qu{h}&\qu{h}\en
\NOtes\qp|\qp&\qp\en\bar
%3er
\NOtes\hp|\islurd0d\hu{d}&\hu{d}\en
\NOtes\qp|\qu{e}&\qu{e}\en
\NOtes\isluru1Q\ql{Q}|\tslur0{d}\zq{d}\qu{^f}&\qu{^f}\en\bar
%4to
\NOtes\ql{_P}|\islurd2d\hl{d}\bsk\isluru3m\qu{g}&\beginmel\islurd0g\qu{g}\en
\NOtes\ql{^M}|\qu{h}&\tslur0{h}\endmel\qu{h}\en
\NOtes\tslur1{N}\ql{N}|\tslur2{d}\ql{d}\bsk\tslur3{o}\qu{_i}&\qu{_i}\en
\NOtes\qp|\qp&\qp\en\bar
%5to
\NOtes\qp|\zh{_i}\isluru0k\hl{k}&\hl{k}\en
\NOtes\isluru1L\ql{L}|&\en
\NOtes\ql{M}|\zq{h}\qu{j}&\ql{j}\en
\NOtes\tslur1{O}\qu{_I}|\tslur0{o}\zq{g}\qu{i}&\ql{_i}\en
\endpiece%
\end{music}%
};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\end{frame}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue on Beamer, I use the Tikz package as follow:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixlyr}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, bending, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\frametitle{?`Qué es \underline{Musixtex}?}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,scale=1.1] (image) at (0,0) {
\hspace*{-0.6cm}\begin{music}
\font\A=phvb8t at 10pt
\font\B=phvb8t at 7pt
\generalmeter{\meterC}
\parindent10mm
\instrumentnumber{2}
\setstaffs1{2}
\setclef16
\setclef2\treble
\setname1{\A Piano}
\setname2{\A Canto}
\setinterstaff{1}{13}%Dist. Sistemas
\nobarnumbers
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Letras}{Ma-nca so-lle-ci-ta pi\`u de-ll'u-sa-to, a-nco-rch\`e}
\setsongraise2{-1.8mm}
\startpiece\addspace\afterruleskip% 
\B\assignlyrics2{Letras}
\znotes|\zchar{10}{\hspace*{-0.7cm}\A Adagio.}&\zchar{10}{\hspace*{-0.7cm}\A Adagio.}\en
\NOtes\hp|\islurd0c\hu{c}&\hu{c}\en
\NOtes\qp|\qu{d}&\qu{d}\en
\NOtes\isluru1P\ql{_P}|\tslur0{c}\zq{c}\qu{e}&\qu{e}\en\bar
%2do
\NOtes\ql{O}|\islurd2c\hl{c}\bsk\isluru3l\qu{f}&\qu{f}\en
\NOtes\ql{L}|\qu{g}&\qu{g}\en
\NOtes\tslur1{M}\ql{M}|\tslur2{c}\ql{c}\bsk\tslur3{n}\qu{h}&\qu{h}\en
\NOtes\qp|\qp&\qp\en\bar
%3er
\NOtes\hp|\islurd0d\hu{d}&\hu{d}\en
\NOtes\qp|\qu{e}&\qu{e}\en
\NOtes\isluru1Q\ql{Q}|\tslur0{d}\zq{d}\qu{^f}&\qu{^f}\en\bar
%4to
\NOtes\ql{_P}|\islurd2d\hl{d}\bsk\isluru3m\qu{g}&\beginmel\islurd0g\qu{g}\en
\NOtes\ql{^M}|\qu{h}&\tslur0{h}\endmel\qu{h}\en
\NOtes\tslur1{N}\ql{N}|\tslur2{d}\ql{d}\bsk\tslur3{o}\qu{_i}&\qu{_i}\en
\NOtes\qp|\qp&\qp\en\bar
%5to
\NOtes\qp|\zh{_i}\isluru0k\hl{k}&\hl{k}\en
\NOtes\isluru1L\ql{L}|&\en
\NOtes\ql{M}|\zq{h}\qu{j}&\ql{j}\en
\NOtes\tslur1{O}\qu{_I}|\tslur0{o}\zq{g}\qu{i}&\ql{_i}\en
\endpiece
\end{music}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The solved output is as follow:
[image: solved]

Bu some reason, there is a slighty space at the end bar ...

Comment: \B\assignlyrics2{Letras}% <- This avoid space at the end.